# outer join of pandas df generated from for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, concatenation

I have a for loop that in the first iteration generates a dataframe like:

```
pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Al", "Si", "K", "Th"], data = [[1,2,3,4]])
```

The second iteration produces a dataframe that looks like:

```
pd.DataFrame(columns = ["W", "Cu"], data = [[5,6]])
```

Both the columns and data variables are generated through the loop in each iteration.
I want to be able to add something at the end of the loop that performs and outer join of each one of the dataframes, such that the final result is:

```
pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Al", "Si", "K", "Th", "W", "Cu"], data = [[1,2,3,4, 0,0], [0,0,0,0, 5,6]])
```

I've tried with append, concat and outer join but can't crack it, because I need a live update on the final dataframe on each iteration, and can't sort it out.

Also, worth to mention that I can't predefine the total amount columns a priori, the elements calculated are dependent on the data and created during the loop.

edit:
Here's the loop:

```
formulas = ("NaAlSiO2", "WCu2")

for form in formulas:

    s = re.findall('([A-Z][a-z]?)([0-9]*)', form)

    perc_weight = []
    atoms = []

    for elem, count in s:

        total_weight = molecular_w_calc(form)
        atoms.append(elem)
        perc_weight.append((Element_mass[elem]*100*int(count)) / total_weight)
        perc_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = np.array(atoms), data = [perc_weight])
```

`Element_mass` is a dictionary with values for each atom.
`perc_df` is the dataframe produced in each iteration.
`molecular_w_calc` returns a single value.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "a live update on the final dataframe on each iteration". But I suspect that you don't really want to be creating a separate DataFrame object each time through the loop. At any rate, it would help to show the actual code you are using.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I've posted the loop as an edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extend the frame iteratively then `concat` should actually work. This

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Al", "Si", "K", "Th"], data = [[1,2,3,4]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["W", "Cu"], data = [[5,6]])
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis='rows')
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

gives you

```
    Al   Si    K   Th    W   Cu
0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  0.0  0.0
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  5.0  6.0
```

---

Just a **suggestion**: Wouldn't you be better off if you do the creation of the underlying data with basic Python only?

Something like

```
import re
import pandas as pd

re_comps = re.compile(r'([A-Z][a-z]?)([0-9]*)')

formulas = ("NaAlSiO2", "WCu2")
elements = {element for formula in formulas
                    for element, _ in re_comps.findall(formula)}
perc_dict = {key: len(formulas) * [None] for key in elements.union({'Formula'})}
for i, formula in enumerate(formulas):
    perc_dict['Formula'][i] = formula
    total_weight = molecular_w_calc(formula)
    for element, count in re_comps.findall(formula):
        count = 1 if count == '' else int(count)
        perc_dict[element][i] = (Element_mass[element] * 100 * count) / total_weight
```

and only then Pandas

```
perc_df = pd.DataFrame(perc_dict)
perc_df.set_index('Formula', drop=True, inplace=True)
perc_df.sort_index(axis='columns', inplace=True)
```

The structure of the resulting `perc_df` looks like (the values are obviously wrong, since I didn't have the `Element_mass` dictionary and `molecular_w_calc` function):

```
           Al   Cu   Na    O   Si    W
Formula                               
NaAlSiO2  1.0  NaN  1.0  2.0  1.0  NaN
WCu2      NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0
```

Comment: I actually found a solution before, but this works too! Thanks!